# Error No session bound to current thread with Hibernate 4 and Spring 3

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am updating my application to Spring 3.2.5 and Hibernate 4.2.7. Everything compiles again, but when I run the application I get:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:990)
at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.sequence.SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl$EventIdInitializer.doInitialize_aroundBody0(SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl.java:182)
at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.sequence.SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl$EventIdInitializer$AjcClosure1.run(SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl.java:1)
at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.sequence.SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl$EventIdInitializer.doInitialize(SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl.java:179)
at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.cache.initializer.BaseCoherenceInitializer.initializeIfNeeded(BaseCoherenceInitializer.java:236)
at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.cache.initializer.BaseCoherenceInitializer.getCache(BaseCoherenceInitializer.java:98)
at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.sequence.SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl.getHighestEventId(SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl.java:120)
at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.sequence.SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl.access$0(SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl.java:118)
at com.traficon.tmsng.server.common.sequence.SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl$SequenceGeneratorInitializer.run(SequenceGeneratorServiceImpl.java:149)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

If you look through the stacktrace, you see the transaction aspect, so I assume that is ok.

I have this in my application context:

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

My sessionFactory is a `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

I have set:
   `hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext`

Any idea what might be wrong?

UPDATE:

It seems only methods annotated with `@Transactional(Propagation.SUPPORTS)` and `@Transactional(Propagation.NEVER)` are not working. If I change them to `Propagation.REQUIRED` then it works. But why? This used to be working fine with Spring 3.0.4 and Hibernate 3.5.6.

Comment: did you enabled and/or updated your OpenSessionInViewFilter?

Comment: I never needed one. I am using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext directly, it is not a webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a known Spring issue it seems. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9020.

The workaround is to use [this class](https://gist.github.com/nexdrew/6992329) and set it as the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` in your hibernate properties in the Spring SessionFactory (which should be a `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` normally)